# Associate with other accounts not working for Server Fault

Tags: support, linked-accounts, association

I have *this* user account linked with my Facebook account. Also, I was successfully able to associate with [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/faq), Super User, Stack Overflow, and 4 other Stack Exchange sites.. but now when I login for the first time on Server Fault (using the Facebook account), it loads as a new one and fails to associate.

I even go to my profile > accounts on Server Fault, and it shows "We found matching accounts on other sites in the Stack Exchange network:" (and shows Android Enthusiasts, Super User, etc..)

I click the button below it "Associate with other sites".. it takes so long and nothing happens. The page just refreshes and nothing is associated.. The main thing is, there's not even an error message displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You generally have to wait a few minutes for the associations to propagate. It is *not* immediate.

Look again in 5-10 minutes.

If that doesn't work, go to the accounts tab, click "unassociate" then click "reassociate" and wait 5-10 minutes.

Comment: It has already been past 10 minutes since I've last tried.. and the "unassociate" button isnt there because its still unassociated..

Comment: @power hmm, you're right. Something is odd there. Taking a deeper look...

Comment: @power nope -- it's what I described. Unassociate, reassociate, wait 5 minutes (note timestamp on this and previous chat message; hover your mouse over the time to see detail). Worked like a charm. (We do need to improve the UI to make it clear this is NOT an immediate thing.)

Comment: Ok, sorry it felt to me like i've waited 10 mins.. I thought this was a bug or some cookies or something.. Btw I got the accounts associated. thanks. Oh and like you said, the work on the UI regarding this, really need!